# Memset function and bool arrays

Tags: c++, initialization, boolean, memset

I was trying to learn about `memset` function and I read an article that we cannot initialise `int` array to 1 using `memset`. But I have declared a `bool` array and initialised it to true using `memset` function.

On printing the array elements the array elements are `1 1 1` rather than true. If initialised to false it gives `0 0 0`.
Also I declared an `int` variable `x` and set its value to `a[0]+a[1]` and on printing `x` it gives me `2`. I am using c++ on devc++. Can anyone explain me the reason?

```cpp
bool a[3]
memset( a,true,3*sizeof(bool))
cout << a[i]; // 1 1 1
int x = a[0] + a[1]; // 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that C and C++ are two different languages (for example, there is no `bool` data type in C), and if your question is about C++, please tag it with C++ instead of C. You can use the "edit" link below your question to fix that.

Comment: `cout` is a C++ thing. Not C. Tags updated

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no array if `int` involved in your code. Whatever bit patters is present in a `bool` variable, it will be evaluated as `0` or `1` even if the binary value is `255`

Comment: A little anecdote regarding the datatype of 'Bool' and why 'initialization' is important:
I once had a fragment of code, that checked an (uninitialized) bool. Once with `!variable` and, in the else part, against `== true`. Neither branch triggered and the debugger later told me, that my bool had a value of 42. I had found my answer.

Comment: _"we cannot initialise int array to 1 using memset"_: I hope you understand the reason.

Comment: In C++ use [`std::uninitialized_fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill). Smart implementations will use `memset` when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof( bool )` in C++ or `sizeof( _Bool )` in C are implementation defined but usually they are equal to `1` that is to the value of `sizeof( char )` and the value true is stored as 1 and the value false is stored as 0.

For example (the C Standard, 6.2.5 Types)

> 2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values
> 0 and 1

So this call of `memset`

```
memset( a,true,3*sizeof(bool));
```

set all elements of the array a to 1.

This statement

```
cout « a[i];
```

outputs boolean values equal to true as integer constants 1. If you want to output as a string you need to use the manipulator `std::boolalpha`. For example

```
cout « std::boolalpha << a[i];
```

In this declaration

```
int x = a[0] + a[1];
```

the operand `a[2]` and `a[1]` yield the value `1`. So their sum is equal to `2`.

Answer (score 2):

When you print out your `bool`s, the stream has a `boolalpha` flag to determine whether they print out as `true`/`false` or as `1`/`0`. If you want them to print out as `true`/`false`, you can do something like:

```cpp
std::cout << std::boolalpha << a[i];
```

I wrote an answer some time ago that goes into more detail about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960054/179910

For the sake of compatibility with C, C++ defined implicit conversions from `int` to `bool` and `bool` to `int`, so `0` converts to `false` and any other value to `true`, while `false` converts to `0` and `true` converts to `1`. So when you do `a[2] + a[1]`, it converts each `bool` to the corresponding `int`, then adds those together. Not always the behavior you'd want, but something that's used in enough C code that they apparently thought it necessary to maintain anyway (and I think they were right).

Getting back to `memset`, the problem with setting `int`s to non-zero values is that `memset` always treats the data you give it as an array of `char`, regardless of the type of data that's actually there. Each `char` (by definition) occupies a single byte. For example, let's assume you have 4-byte `int`s on your implementation. In this case, if you use `memset` to set those `int`s to `1`, what you're going to get is each `int` set to the value `0x01010101` (which in decimal will be 16,843,009).

In C++, `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` tends to work out better as a rule. It's implemented as a template so its behavior is tailored to the type being written, so if you use it to fill an array of `int` with `1`, each `int` will actually have the value `1`.