# Why does this boolean function return true (74) and the program display 74?

Tags: c++

I am just messing around with the function and somehow *palindromes* returns 74. I am using Visual studio 2022. Was it supposed to not return anything and catch compiler error since false is never returned in the case below?

```
bool palindromes(string str) {
    if (str.length() == 0 || str.length() == 1) return true;

    if (str[0] == str[str.length() - 1])
        palindromes(str.substr(1, str.length() - 2));
    else
        return false;
}


int main()
{
    cout << palindromes("lol");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually return something from the function.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960015/c-printing-boolean-what-is-displayed) help at all?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. I suggest compiling with warnings turned up (and reading them when they happen), so the compiler tells you when you forget to return a value on certain code paths.

Comment: From C++ Standard, 6.6.3:    Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behaviour in a value-returning function.

Comment: Off-topic: This recursive variant of creating substrings again and again is pretty inefficient! Rather make this function a frontend for an actual worker iterating on iterators. And you actually need one single test as stop condition: `str.length() <= 1`...

Comment: Have you considered an iterative variant? `if(!str.empty()) { auto b = str.begin(); e = std::prev(str.end()); while(b < e) { if(*b != *e) { return false; } } return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you ignored the warning:

```
warning C4715: 'palindromes': not all control paths return a value
```

This is a sin.

Answer (score 5):

`palindromes(str.substr(1, str.length() - 2));` is  a typical mistake with recursion. I suppose you want to do something with the value returned from that call, but you ignore it. Recursive functions work very much the same as non-recursive functions, there is no implicit `return`.

Very much related, the function does not return something when this condition `str.length() == 0 || str.length() == 1` is `false` but this condition `str[0] == str[str.length() - 1]` is `true`.

---

This line

```
palindromes(str.substr(1, str.length() - 2));
```

Does nothing. The function gets a parameter passed by value and the returned value is ignored.

Not returning something from a function that is declared to return something is undefined behavior.

---

Fix:

```
return palindromes(str.substr(1, str.length() - 2));
```

There might be other issues though.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use recursion for what is a linear problem. Your multiple string copies add unnecessary overhead.

An alternative:

`return std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size() / 2, str.rbegin());`

This is readable and therefore less prone to bugs - your function not returning a value on all control paths is a bug: `str.length() - 2` is vulnerable to `unsigned` arithmetic.