# How to overload operator<<(double const&) in an inherited std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stringstream

I would like to overwrite the `operator<<` such that:

```cpp
double d = 3.0;
mycustomstringstream << "Hello World " << d << "what a nice day.";
std::cout << mystream.str() << std::endl;
```

will produce the output:

```
Hello World (double)(3.00000000000)what a nice day.
```

Remark to avoid confusion: Every double shall be printed this way then, with a "(double)(" in front and a ")" behind, whenever a stream implementing my operator is used. The stream should come at least with all the functionality of string-stream, and I prefer to not have to fully re-implement the streamby myself. The purpose of the question is not for exercise but to save time/tediousness/errors from otherwise having to wrap a function call `double_to_string` around every streamed double d.

## What I tried

### Overriding

Since I would be fine for `double`s to be printed like so, I boldly implemented:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, double const& d){
  o<<"(double)("<< d << ")";
  return o;
}
```

That does not work because the compiler explains about ambiguity (since that operator is already defined).

### Inheriting

So as in the beginning, I am fine to inherit from `std::stringstream` and just replace the definition of that operator for my `customstringstream`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

class MyCustomStringStream: public std::stringstream{};

MyCustomStringStream& operator<<(MyCustomStringStream& o, double const& d){
  o<<"(double)("<< ( (std::stringstream)(o) << d ) << ")";
  return o;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
```

So then instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStringStream: public std::stringstream{
    std::stringstream aux;
public:
    MyStringStream& operator<<(double const& d){
        aux.str() = "";
        aux << std::scientific << "((double)(" << d << ")";
        *this << aux.str();
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    double d = 12.3;
    MyStringStream s;
    s << "Hello World " << d << "what a nice day.";
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
}
```

But this still prints:

```
Hello World 12.3what a nice day.
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/daG3bo6hv)

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to pass a const reference to a double. Just pass by value.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You are right. I was just "going through the motions" :D

Comment: As you already discovered, overloading a stream operator for a built-in type is not a good idea. Is there a use for your class `MyStringStream`, or did you introduce it as an exercise, to give yourself experience overloading `operator<<`?

Comment: Stream operators are best written for your own classes, e.g., `std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& ost, MyClass const& mc);` Output is easy. The tricky stuff is coding a bullet-proof input `operator>>`.

Comment: I think you can't get away with simply overloading `operator<<` for `double`. By starting out with `s << "Hello World "` you are calling `std::stringstream`'s `operator<<` for `const char *`, which returns a `std::stringstream &`, and it's that object reference's version of the operator for double that is being called. If you remove the `<< "Hello World` part, your overloaded operator gets called.

Comment: @jkb that would influence the output of ALL doubles which may or may not be what you want.  I usually opt for being explicit

Comment: @PepijnKramer Based on the code the OP posted, I gather that influencing the output of ALL doubles output through his derived class is in fact what he wanted. I was just pointing out *why* his overload wasn't being called, and how to make it do so.

Comment: @tbxfreeware Yes, not as exercise. I want to make sure that when generating program code from string-stream with numbers of double or quadfloat or __float128, there is no loss of accuracy for any types longer than double. That is, I would overload the print operator for any types to make sure all digits are used at compile time of the string-streamed code.

Comment: @jkb. That is exactly why I used aux. So aux's is called for <<operator on double, and that operator had not been tampered with by MyCustomStringStream. And the actual printing is by accessing the str() function of inherited stringstream. So I still don't see why it does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because the `<< "Hello World"` part is not using code in your class, but is instead using the base class's (`std::stringstream`') overload of `operator <<` for `const char *`. That function returns a reference to itself, not to your derived class. Because the base class returned a reference to a `std::stringstream` (again, not an object of `MyStringStream`), it is that object's overload of `operator<<` for `double` that is called. If you try using just `s << d << "what a nice day` you will see that your overload is called. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jkb. Ah, thanks. This makes sense. Okay now I understand why the problem occurs. ..I still have to figure out a solution :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams *are* designed to support this sort of customization, though they way they support it may not initially be as obvious as you'd like (and implementing it correctly is kind of a pain too).

When you write a number to a stream, the formatting is delegated to the stream's locale. That locale contains (among other things) a `num_put` facet, which is what actually formats a number as desired for the stream.

The num_put facet has overloads of `do_put` for each of the standard numeric types, including `double`. Since you (apparently) want to leave other types formatted normally, and apply your special formatting only to `double`s, you override only the `do_put` overload for `double`.

To format a number with this, you imbue your stream with a locale that contains an instance of that `num_put` facet:

```cpp
  std::ostringstream os;

  std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), new my_num_put<char>);

  os.imbue(loc);
```

Then write a `double` to the stream:

```cpp
  os << 123.456 << "\n";

  // and copy the result to standard output so we can see it:
  std::cout << os.str();
```

For a proof of concept, your `do_put` can use a stringstream to convert the `double` to a string, then copy the prefix, string, and suffix to the output sequence. Moving beyond proof of concept is a bit more work though.

To format the number correctly, we need to get all the formatting information from the `ios_base` that's passed to `do_put`, and set the formatting for our temporary stringstream accordingly. For example:

```cpp
    std::ostringstream temp;

    // copy flags, width and precision:
    temp.flags(b.flags());
    temp.width(b.width());
    temp.precision(b.precision());
    
    temp << v;
```

Figuring out everything that needs to be copied over to do all formatting correctly is left as an exercise for the interested reader. Here's a quick test program with semi-complete code as described above:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <ios>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class charT, class OutputIterator = std::ostreambuf_iterator<charT>>
class my_num_put : public std::num_put<charT, OutputIterator> {
public:
  using iter_type = typename std::num_put<charT, OutputIterator>::iter_type;
  using char_type = typename std::num_put<charT, OutputIterator>::char_type;

  iter_type do_put(iter_type i, std::ios_base &b, char_type fill, double v) const override {
    std::string prefix = "(double)(";
    std::string suffix = ")";

    std::ostringstream temp;
    temp.flags(b.flags());
    temp.width(b.width());
    temp.precision(b.precision());
    temp.fill(fill);
    
    temp << v;
    std::string const &s = temp.str();

    std::copy(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), i);
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), i);
    std::copy(suffix.begin(), suffix.end(), i);
    return i;
  }
};

int main() {

  std::ostringstream os;

  std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), new my_num_put<char>);

  os.imbue(loc);

  // test a minimal case:
  os << 1.234 << "\n";
 
  // test with a few formatting flags:
  os << std::setw(17) << 123.456 << "\n";
  os << std::setw(14) << std::setprecision(12) << std::left << 9876.54321 << "\n";
  std::cout << os.str();
}
```

The result I get is about as you'd apparently hope/expect:

```
(double)(1.234)
(double)(          123.456)                
(double)(9876.54321    )
```

This should work with essentially any stream, not just a `stringstream`. And once you've imbued a stream with this locale, you don't have to make any further changes to other code for all `double`s you write to that stream to be formatted this way.

For the moment, I've left the `precision` and `width` applying only to the width and precision used for the number itself, so when you write something out with `std::setw(10)`, the output will be 10 + the size of prefix and suffix you use. Depending on your viewpoint, it may well make more sense to subtract the size of your prefix+suffix from the width applied to the number itself, so the width will be the total field size, not just the size of the number part.

So, while I'd still consider it a proof of concept rather than finished, fully-tested code, I'd say this does give a basic idea of an approach that should be able to accomplish your goal (and depending on how lofty a goal you've setting, *may* already be adequate).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt ?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: I've tried that, but never gotten it to work correctly. Code looks roughly like: `std::ostringstream temp; std::ios &bb = dynamic_cast<std::ios &>(b); temp.copyfmt(bb);` (in a try-block, in case the dynamic_cast fails). The dynamic_cast succeeds, but copyfmt throws a seg-fault (and I've never tracked down why).

Comment: Why cast? All streams inherit from std::ios, a simple initialisation with no cast should suffice.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: Without a cast it won't compile. The source you need to copy from is the `ios_base &` that's passed as the second parameter to `do_put`, and what `copyfmt` expects is a `ios &`. There's an implicit conversion from `ios` to `ios_base`, but not from `ios_base` to `ios`.

Comment: Good point. I'd forgotten about locales in my answer. This sort of radical change isn't what locales were designed for -- the goal is more things like using `,` instead of `.` in European (and other) locales. But as specified by the standard, such code should work (although many, myself included, would consider it abuse).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I can sort of understand considering it abuse. I've personally adopted an attitude that I before I consider something abuse, I have to be able to articulate a fairly specific reason that I think it's abuse, and (especially) a fairly clear dividing line between what's abusive and what isn't. In this case, about all I can come up with is that locales should perhaps be tied to some real-world convention--but the "C" locale isn't. It's basically  just "do the simplest thing that sort of works". So while I sympathize, I have a hard time agreeing.

Comment: I guess my definition of abuse is whether it is something that a normal practitioner of the language might expect. Which really doesn't help much, as what is a normal practitioner of the language. I regularly derive from `streambuf`, for example -- I don't know how many C++ programmers are aware of the possibilities there. In this case, I guess I'd argue that the locales should be symmetric: if you create a special output, you should also provide a corresponding input.

Comment: And the "C" local is very definitely US -- everywhere in Europe, at least, we use a comma as the decimal separator. About the only thing about the "C" local which makes it "universal" is that it is the locale used to parse C++ sources.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There is the minor detail that it's the only locale that's guaranteed to be universally available...

Comment: @JamesKanze: As far as it being something a normal practitioner of the language would expect, I guess I have a bit of difficulty with that. For example, consider the `num_punct` facet I posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960054/179910). I'd posit this one fits *precisely* with the intended purpose of the `num_punct` facet's existence. But many still don't expect it, because facets are so poorly known. I'd also note that if it were solely about things like using `,` vs. `.`, there would be no reason for `num_put` to exist at all, as that requirement is met by `num_punct`.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you think about inheritance it is usually not the first solution you should think of. I would not derive from a stream anyway (usually inheriting from STL types is not recommended, though streams allow for this).

There is a more reusable solution for your situation - make a helper formatting object ([demo](https://onlinegdb.com/PKtw7P3E8)).

At least with this (C++17) approach, you can still mix normal and scientific formatting (and still have a central point in your code where you can manage what your formatting should look like):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename type_t>
struct as_scientific
{
    explicit as_scientific(type_t& v) : value{v}{};
    type_t value;
};

template<typename type_t>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const as_scientific<type_t>& scientific)
{
    os << std::scientific << "((" << typeid(type_t).name() << ")(" <<  scientific.value << ")";
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    double d = 12.3;
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "Hello World " << as_scientific{d} << "what a nice day.";
    std::cout << s.str() << "\n";

    // or directly
    std::cout << as_scientific{d} << "\n";
}
```

For C++20, there is the `<format>` library, which can help you with custom for matters.

Comment: First sentence seems a little garbled. Did you mean 'Whatever you think inheritance is usually not the *solution*'? Otherwise this is clearly a better approach to the problem. Save inheritance from stream classes for when you have a new input or output device, not for formatting tricks.

Comment: This is literally the same approach how many of the standard  `<iomanip>` stream manipulators are implemented.

Comment: @john fixed, you where absolutely right, And true stream inheritance should only be used for that.

Comment: Also for a real library I would further restrict the as_scientific struct to only accept floating_point values using either SFINEA (C++17 and before) or concepts (C++20)

Comment: Sorry, but that is exactly missing the point. The point is to save time by sparing to put a function call around every d whenever I want to print it into a file. So that is as tedious as what I have right now: std::string double_to_string(double){ return std::string("(double)("+std::to_string(d)+")"; }.

Comment: @GRamon focusing on some keystrokes to save can often lead to poor design. The solution presented in this answer is flexible and gets the thing done. Typically you want formatting to be independent of the type of stream, you want to pipe the same to a file or stdout or whatever. Once you try to do that with your approach it gets really tedious

Comment: @GRamon Implicitness often bites back, in the end you write code only once and it doesn't take much time (you or others will read it far more often in the future). Already you see how much time it has cost you to write this code, debug it, ask questions about it... imagine how many `as_scientific{d}` statements you could have written in that time. So no I don't think I miss your point, I think your point shows you're not that experienced yet ;)

Comment: Also this design adheres to the S of the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) which as a software developer you should know about.   "Single repsonsibility" means you have formatting as one responsibility and how to stream data (to a device) as a seperate independent responsibility. Which means you should not put them in the same class.

Comment: @PepijnKramer iostreams design utterly fails the S, what do you want from us mere mortals?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI:I have to disagree. iostreams are actually pretty carefully factored. Their big shortcoming is poor documentation, so most people don't know what to do, and poor naming, so it's hard to figure out on your own. There are other shortcomings, but the basic design is really much better than most people realize.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: the mirror of the SRS is that when there's already something to handle a task, you shouldn't add another to do the same thing (which is exactly what you're doing here).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Fair point.

Answer (score 1):

`std::basic_ostream<C,T>& operator<<( double value )` is a non-virtual member function of `std::basic_ostream<C,T>`.

- The concept of overriding only applies to virtual member functions.
- You cannot overload a member function of a class that you don't own with another member function.
- You can overload a member function with a non-member function, but in your case it will be ambiguous because the arguments are exactly the same.
- You can inherit and overload for an inherited class (with a member or a non-member function), but due to the chaining of `operator<<`, your function will only be selected if your `double` is the first thing you output. If you do `mystream << 3.0` you will see the desired result. However if you do something like `mystream << "Hello" << 3.0`, then `(mystream << "Hello")` returns `ostream&`, and the `ostream` member function is selected. To make your code work, you would need to implement **all** overloads of `operator<<` for your class (member and non-member) and make them all return a reference to your class. This can be done with a catch-all template, but catch-all templates are dangerous. And it won't work anyway if you need to pass your stream down to some function with a name different from `operator<<`.

So you can see that what you want to do is not feasible. Almost can be done, but not quite.

Answer (score 1):

`ostream` isn't designed to be customized in that way. Although it can (and often is, including in the standard) derived from, all the derivations do is initialize it with a different `streambuf`, and possibly add functions to access any additional functionality in the `streambuf`. You cannot realistically change the meaning of `operator<<` for the types provided by the standard, even when they are broken (for example, `std::complex`). Streams are defined to be customized by derivation only with regards to the data sink or source (`streambuf`). You can add `operator<<` for user defined types, but you cannot change the meaning of that operator for the types for which the standard defines it. (This is much the same philosophy as for operator overloading in general. You can extend the language to handle your types, but you cannot change the behavior of types defined by the standard.)

Comment: As my answer suggests, I'm forced to disagree. Streams are designed to support customized formatting (though this exact sort of customized formatting probably isn't exactly what anybody had in mind).

Comment: @JerryCoffin They're designed to support customized formatting of user defined types. They're extensible, but you cannot change the meaning for existing types. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting @jbk 's comment:

It doesn't work because the << "Hello World" part is not using code in your class, but is instead using the base class's (std::stringstream') overload of operator << for const char *. That function returns a reference to itself, not to your derived class. Because the base class returned a reference to a std::stringstream (again, not an object of MyStringStream), it is that object's overload of operator<< for double that is called. If you try using just s << d << "what a nice day you will see that your overload is called. Does that make sense?

So then logically the solution is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStringStream: public std::stringstream{
    std::stringstream aux;
public:
    MyStringStream& operator<<(double const& d){
        aux.str() = "";
        aux << std::scientific << "((double)(" << d << ")";
        *this << aux.str();
        return *this;
    }
    //
    template<typename T>
    MyStringStream& operator<<(T const& t){
        static_cast<std::stringstream&>(*this) << t;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    double d = 12.3;
    MyStringStream s;
    s << "Hello World " << d << "what a nice day.";
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: see what happens when you pass eg `std::endl` https://godbolt.org/z/crYWKPobz

Comment: the inheritance is also broken. When you use `MyStringStream` polymorphically: https://godbolt.org/z/x9cTc8xKP

Comment: don't get me wrong. I am not here to annoy you ;). Just trying to make you understand that inheriting from the stream is the tedious solution (If you want to make it actually work properly) and your solution is still missing a lot

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai. I get your point, and this is much appreciated. Thank you. The issue is Kramer's solution isn't better than what I currently have, and it _is_ tedious. I would really like to find a better solution. Can something be done with requirements on T to avoid the issues you pointed out?

Comment: Also, I don't think the line `aux.str() = ""` is doing what you think. It does not clear the buffer. I think you want `aux.str("")`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai actually the problem with `endl` is fixable and the problem with `setfill` is that you are not using it correctly (should have a character parameter, not integer). But the inheritance problem of course is not fixable.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI ups, my fault. Removed that comment. `std::endl` is fixable, but still I wouldnt suggest to go that route. As someone mentioned, manipulating io is for iomanipulators not for implementing a new type of stream.